# Stock email app does not include certain attachments when forwarding email

Tags: stock-email-app

I am trying to forward an email with a powerpoint file attachment to a colleague in the company using the stock email app.

When I click forward , the paper clip shows up as though the attachment is being attached , however the recipient does not get the attachment.

I tried this with attached powerpoints that arrived from another company site over an encrypted email connection and it always fails to attach.

Other powerpoint files that I get from my gmail account always are included when I forward the emails.

So there is something unusual about these attachments that the stock Android email app cannot handle.

The kicker is that the same exact email can be forwarded with the attachment just fine using the iOS email app. I tried with my iOS phone which I also use from time to time.
So it seems to be a OS specific issue .

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to tell you that Android's email forwarding function is broekn at least since 2009. Google is closing all bugreports and ignoring thisn problem. This kind of problem is easy to hide so those who don't an Android device won't know about it. And since fixing it won't bring in any money...there's no need to fix it.

Comment: Do you have a source or any evidence for your claim that Google is deliberately ignoring the problem? Please add this information to your answer.